# Ruby SSLServer closes when connected to by non-ssl client

Tags: ruby, ssl, openssl

I have a simple SSL server in ruby:

```
require "socket"
require "openssl"
tcp_server = TCPServer.new("0.0.0.0", 8443)
ctx = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
ctx.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new File.read params["ssl-key"]
ctx.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new File.read params["ssl-cert"]
server = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLServer.new(tcp_server, ctx)

#client handling code
loop do
client = server.accept
client.puts("Hello!")
client.close
end
```

When I start the server, it works and I can connect to it with ssl, but whenever I connect without ssl, I get an error: OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError and the server stops and I can not connect again. I have seen solutions for this that involve modifying the code of the SSLServer code but for my usecase, that is not feasible. Is there any other solution for this that can be solved my modifying my code that I have?

Comment: Please post the actual error. If it's an exception, you can rescue it.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs It is an exception, and when I rescue it, no exception raises and the program keeps running, but I can no longer connect to the server.